# OS Updates on Azure Web Applications

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

our web application is experiencing permission errors, from time to time we are receiving this exception :

```
Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache\..' is denied.
```

this is the call stack

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache\umbraco-plugins.RD0003FF29ADB0.list' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at Umbraco.Core.PluginManager..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IRuntimeCacheProvider runtimeCache, ProfilingLogger logger, Boolean detectChanges)
at Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.Initialize()
at Umbraco.Web.WebBootManager.Initialize()
at Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

however we are not capable of reproducing the error, we tried restarting, up-scaling,  down-scaling, changing instance size - it newer. 
We do not have any evidence to prove that it is OS-Update,  the  main reason why we believe it is related to OS Update is as it is happening on all running instances at the same time (+5/-5 seconds). It comes out of nowhere periodically, and usually on Tuesdays or  Wednesdays, however we can not ever reproduce it.

our only assumption is that it is caused by OS-Update (or similar system event - any idea which?) in azure web application. To get a better handle on the issue we would like to know.

- can I get last windows update time?
- if not can I at least get
  system uptime ?
- and is it by any means possible to initiate windows update or postpone it until the moment I need it  ?

thanks 
almir

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what drove you to think that your exception came from or is related to an "os-udpate". Please, post the full stack trace of your exception. It could help understand the cause.

Comment: I updated question to clarify this part, hope it helps, if not please let me know

Comment: You said you can not reproduce the issue, does it means that the issue does not appear anymore? Besides, system updates of Azure app service web app is controlled by Azure itself, we seems not able to know when the system updates the next time will appear on Azure app service.

Comment: hi I updated it to clafiry this, it is happening over and over again : "It comes out of nowhere periodically, and usually on Tuesdays or Wednesdays, however we can not ever reproduce it".

Comment: You can try to publish your application to another Azure app service web app and check if same issue appears. Perhaps something wrong with that specific web app.